# Nodejs Expressjs and MongoDb

Tags: node.js, express

I have created two models , oders.js and users.js and two routes index.js and users.js ,my aim is just to save data from users.js file to mongodb (Userschema)but not working post method in users.js file is not loading , please check the users.js model and let me know if there is any issue, one more , if we are creating more than one model in node so do we need to create connection in each model ?
here is the code of models.
users.js

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');`enter code here`
var conn=mongoose.connection;

var UserSchema=mongoose.Schema({
name:String,
    department:String,
    designation:String

});

var UserModel=mongoose.model('users',UserSchema);

module.exports=UserModel;
```

Here is Order.js file

```
        var mongoose=require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var conn=mongoose.connection;

var OrderSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    item:String,
    price:Number,
    quamtity:Number,
    total:Number

});

var OrderModel=mongoose.model('orders',OrderSchema);

module.exports=OrderModel;
```

---

Here is the code of routes
Users.js

```
    var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var Usersmodel=require('../models/users');
var query=Usersmodel.find({});`enter code here

router.get('/showusers', function(req, res, next) {

  query.exec(function(err ,doc){
    if(err)throw err;
    res.render('users',{title:"Show all users",rows:doc});

  });

});

router.post('/showusers',function(req , res ,next){



  var newrec=new Users({
    name:req.body.name,
    department:req.body.department,
    designation:req.body.designation

  })

  newrec.save(function(err,doc){
    if(err)throw err;
    query.exec(function(err,doc){
      if(err)throw err;
      res.render('users',{rows:doc});
    });

  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Orders route is working fine but users.js post method is show 500 error not loading

Comment: remove `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');` from users.js. You don't need to connect multiple times to db

Comment: Still not working
POST /users/showusers 500 , this is the status showing

Comment: Let me know if any one can help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please remove connections from your model files. It will create problem due to multiple connections. here you go

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

var Usersmodel = require('../models/users');
//var query=Usersmodel.find({});`enter code here

router.get('/showusers', function (req, res, next) {

    Usersmodel.find({}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('users', {
            title: "Show all users",
            rows: doc
        });

    });

});

router.post('/showusers', function (req, res, next) {
    Usersmodel.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        department: req.body.department,
        designation: req.body.designation
    }, function (err, response) {
        Usersmodel.find({}, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('users', {
                title: "Show all users",
                rows: doc
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes Sir , working , but it requires to refresh the page and also showing error , Typeerror: res.render is not a function.

Comment: Wait a min, editing code a little. We passed res as callback for create, thus the problem

Comment: Select it as correct answer please if it worked. And please leave an upvote as well :D